# Ampere's Law and 3th Newton's Law

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetostatics

In the textbooks of REITZ/MILFORD/CHRISTY(Fundaments...) or WANGNESS(Eletromagnetic fields)it is said that Ampere’s Law  breaks 'aparently’ the  3ª Newton’s Law. Wangness explains in this way:

Ampere’s Law$\displaystyle\rightarrow F_Ca\rightarrow_Cb= \frac{\mu_0}{4\pi}\int_{Ca}^{}\int_{Cb}{}\frac{Ids \times (I'ds' \times \hat{R})}{R^2}$

The assumption of breakink the 3th Neowton’s Law, derives, as is obvious, from not conmutativity ofvectorial product .But applying the property of that product according to

$A\times(B\times C) = B(A\cdot B) - C(A\cdot C)$

becomes that integrand of Ampere’s Law rest:

$\displaystyle II' ds'(ds\cdot \frac{\hat{R}}{R^2})-\frac{II'\hat{}R(ds\cdot ds')}{R^2}$

So raises again the integrand of Ampere’s Law, finallly it’s confirmed that 3th Newton Lay is not violated because the integrals are equal; in brief, they have this form:

$\displaystyle F_Ca\rightarrow Cb = \frac{-\mu_0 II'}{4\pi}\int_{Cb}^{}\int_{Ca}^{}\frac{(ds\cdot ds')\hat{R}}{R^2}$

In fact, applying the mentioned vectorial product property and becomes to product [TEX]II'[/TEX], it’s clear that it’s irrelevant that any circuit has differents I and I’ to calcúlate Ampere’s Law.

Well, on this occasion, I believe, in my opinion, that there is no place the  doubt that both authors have about the violation or not of Newton's third Law. This, for the simple reason that, given Ampere's Law to find the reciprocal force between two closed circuits, it seems clear to me that the force that each of them exerts on the other will depend on the current intensity that each one has.  If the intensity of the circuits are $C_a > C_b$, bigger should be the force of $C_a$ over $C_b$ que no a la inversa. Mathematics says the contrary but I'm not convinced.

Comment: I had read somewhere that, Newton's law doesn't work in QM. And Newton's law doesn't work for wave either. From both statement, I will say that Newton's law also violate EM.

Comment: You formula for triple cross product is wrong. Actually it should be linear on $A,B,C$ and reads as follows $\bf {A}\times (\bf {B}\times \bf{C})=\bf {B}(\bf {A}.\bf {C})-\bf {C}(\bf{A}.\bf{B}) $